# 2019 Macbook Pro, Thunderbolt 3 and monitor daisy chaining

Tags: display, thunderbolt, displayport, thunderbolt-display

Is there a way to make it work? I have Asus 27" VA279HAL and was considering buying Dell 34" U3419W. Dell monitor has USB-C with DP 1.4 Alt Mode, but no Thunderbolt. I've now realised I wouldn't be able to daisy chain them. Would any of the screens with Thunderbolt work?